# need help with a formula for compound interest for a saving account where the user makes monthly deposits.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

First time user sorry about the format,so I know the formula for finding compound interest is as follows.

$A = P (1 + r/n)^{ nt}$ 
$A=$ future value
$P=$ the initial investment
$r=$ annual interest rate
$n=$ number of times compounded
$t =$ the number of years the money is invested

But my question is what in case the user starts with \$1000, but each month deposits \$75? How do you show that using the formula above?

Comment: Any thoughts/questions/comments on the answer I posted?

Comment: Earth to user, come in, please.

Comment: oh thanks sorry I haven't been on for a while.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll assume the interest is compounded monthly, and the deposit is made at the end of each month, after the interest for that month has been added.

So the original \$1000 grows to $1000(1+r/12)^k$, where $k=12t$ is the number of compounding periods.

The first \$75 grows to $75(1+r/12)^{k-1}$.

The second \$75 grows to $75(1+r/12)^{k-2}$.

And so on. The number of \$75 deposits is $k$, one at the end of each month, so these deposits grow to $$75(1+r/12)^{k-1}+75(1+r/12)^{k-2}+\cdots+75(1+r/12)^0$$ 
This is a geometric progression with first term $75$ [reading right to left], common ratio $1+r/12$, and $k$ terms. You know how to add up such a geometric progression? Good. Then add on the $1000(1+r/12)^k$, and you have your answer.